# How to customize Apache Error Log Format?

Tags: apache

According to [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlogformat) a user should be able to change the error log format. The following example shows what supplementary information is logged in the error log in addition to the actual log message.

```
ErrorLogFormat "[%t] [%l] [pid %P] %F: %E: [client %a] %M"
```

I am interested only in the log message "%M". I do not want to see anything else in the log file.
Therefore, in my vhost configuration I added the following line.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  ErrorLogFormat "%M"
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration removed "pid", "IP address", etc. But two strings (Apache error code AH01215 and cgi script path) which are not even mentioned in ErrorLogFormat are still added to the log messages. The Apache log looks like this:

```
 AH01215: My log message1: /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/script.cgi
 AH01215: My log message2: /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/script.cgi
 ...
```

I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to suppress this cgi script path string "/var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/script.cgi" as well as Apache error code "AH01215".

Comment: I have the same problem and would like to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the Apache mod `cgi` that is where the error code is added. The code comes in `%M`, so you can't remove it with the log format.
Switch to `cgid` to remove the `AH01215` from the log. This fixed it for me.
In Ubuntu:

```
a2dismod cgi
a2enmod cgid
```